# How to map a column name with spaces in it to a POCO property?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am working on database table which has a column name with a space in it, for example "Level Description".

I cannot change the column name. Now I have an Entity Framework model class for this table and the compiler is complaining about this property, because property names can't contain spaces!

How can I define the column with space in my class?

```
[Table("StudyLevel")]
public class StudyLevelModel
{
    [Key]
    public byte StudyLevelID { get; set; } 

    // How to map this to the column "Level Description"?
    public string Level Description { get; set; }

    public string SLevelType { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IsActive { get; set; }
    public string ESID { get; set; }
    public string RID { get; set; }
    public byte LevelSearchGroup { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You don't **have** to have your model property names exactly matching your table column names; there is a `[Column]` attribute you can apply to map a property to the column:

```
[Table("StudyLevel")]
public class StudyLevelModel
{
    [Key]
    public byte StudyLevelID { get; set; } 
    [Column("Level Description")]
    public string LevelDescription { get; set; }
    public string SLevelType { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IsActive { get; set; }
    public string ESID { get; set; }
    public string RID { get; set; }
    public byte LevelSearchGroup { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @toxic no problem, just a hint - you don't have to declare nullable bool as `Nullable<bool>` you can simply use `bool?` as a bit of syntactic sugar.

Comment: in order to use Column attribute one has to add using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

Comment: Was in the same situation as OP. Stored procedure was returning a [Fulfillment Name] field and this solution works perfectly for me.
Thank you for putting together such a clear example.

Comment: Trivia Note - if you need to include `Order` for a Composite Key (like you would with a model that reflects a SQL view), you have to do it like this: `[Column(name: "Some Name", Order = 0)]` (...then `Order = 1`, `Order = 2`, etc...)

Comment: @vapcguy I would personally try to avoid composite (and natural) keys where possible. If requirement change, you would not like to be in situation to change primary key.

Comment: @Muflix You don't have a choice if you are using a model against a SQL View about doing a composite key. You HAVE to do it just as I described. There is no primary key on a SQL View - primary keys are on tables.

Comment: @vapcguy: good point. If you cannot change the view and uniqueness of the view is composed of multiple columns, you probably have to use composite key.

Answer (score 8):

Use the [ColumnAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.columnattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to set the name:

```
 [Column(Name="Level Description")]
 public string LevelDescription { get; set; }
```

Comment: it work without name   like [Column("Level Description")]
    public string LevelDescription { get; set; }

Comment: This is the solution. Good you made an edit. The property in your model will be camel cased (normal) and the name of the column in the database will meet the required.

Comment: Trivia Note - if you need to include `Order` for a Composite Key (like you would with a model that reflects a SQL view), you have to do it like this: `[Column(name: "Some Name", Order = 0)]` (...then `Order = 1`, `Order = 2`, etc...) But it will work, as shown above, for a model that is going against a SQL table. You don't need `Name=`, though, like @Toxic said.